# if statement to check if the user has left the text box empty - issue

Tags: c#, if-statement, webforms, textbox

I have a web form with a text box where the user enters a URL so by default I have put an https:// but if the user does not enter a URL after and leaves it empty I want to show an error. I have used

```
if (textBox1.TextLength <= 9)
{
    // code
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `Length` check, use equality operator with `.Text` property to check exact text in the text box.

```
//This means, there is only "https://" is written in the text box
if(textBox1.Text == "https://")
{
   //Show an error. Here user did not enter anything
}
else
{
    //Your implementation
}
```